# Лечить болезни — плеоназм?

Tags: плеоназм

Есть выражение "лечить болезни". Но я вдруг задумалась: а не плеоназм ли это? Понятно, что что-то другое, кроме болезней, лечить не будут.))) То есть, достаточно только слова "лечить", а вот "болезни" уже лишнее.
То есть, насколько грамотно выражение "лечить болезни"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

От контекста зависит. Если у нас рассказ про больного, и врач говорит: "Я буду его лечить", то нет смысла писать: "Я буду лечить его болезни", иначе выйдет плеоназм. 
Однако, следует понимать, что "лечить" — многозначное слово, а потому, иногда, когда нет контекста, данное уточнение ("болезни") является необходимостью. 
Поэтому, ответ на вопрос здесь неоднозначен — и да, и нет. Всегда следует исходить из контекста. Но всё же, в большинстве случаев, выражение "лечить болезни" будет содержать плеоназм.

Answer (score 3):

О том, что выражение "лечить болезнь" допустимо, говорит, например, устоявшееся понятие "неизлечимых болезней" (не только неизлечимых больных). И в русском не так много подходящих слов, которые можно "направить" на болезнь, поставив её в винительный падеж. Что будем делать с вашей болезнью? Естественно, мы будем её лечить, а не "устранять", "уничтожать" или "изгонять". Такой контекст почти вынуждает применение к болезни слова "лечить".

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас слово **лечить** имеет и другое значение — поучать, загружать лишней информацией. Нередко слышишь фразы: "Что ты меня лечишь!?" Ой, только не надо меня лечить!" Так что, **болезнь** помогает раскрыть нужный смысл.